# What gem should I use to connect to facebook api from rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku

I'm really confused, I'm trying to create a rails app on heroku that connects to facebook. The app needs to access the facebook api (maybe using the koala gem) therefore I need some user access token..

what gems should I use to connect?
P.S. my app on facebook is set on "app on facebook" and "website with facebook login" (what I really want is a website with facebook login AND access to facebook api...)

any idea/clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify on what do you mean by connect? If you need your app to 'be' on facebook, you may want to point a facebook app towards your heroku app https://developers.facebook.com/apps, if you want to take info from facebooks API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

[image: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/]